How to show plotly plot in `blastula` rmd file
i tried to embed plotly plot in rmd file. When I knit this in RStudio plot shows but in mail send via blastula package it disapears.
My code
title: "test_pliku_rmd"
output: blastula::blastula_email
date: "2024-09-27"

```{r Wyświetlenie_wykres_target, echo=TRUE, fig.height=5, fig.width=18}


plot_ly(
  domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
  
  value = 10,
  title = list(text = "Realizacja targetu"),
  type = "indicator",
  mode = "gauge+number",
  gauge = list(
    axis = list(
      range = c(0,20)
    )
  )
)

```

How can I send this plotly plot via mail?
